# kotlin using data class generics type

Tags: kotlin

Hi there I have gone thru the kotlin documentation and haven't found anything. What I want to do is have a generic thar must be a data class, something like

```
data class MyData(val pop1:Long,val pop2:String,...)

fun class MyGenericClass<T : isDataClass>(o : T){
    // This is the important part
    fun useCopy(value : Long) = t.copy(pop1 = value)
}
```

What I really need to achieve is to be able to use the copy function of data classes in a generic way(pop1 will always be  a member of my data classes)

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what if the class doesn't have a `pop1` member?  My suggestion would be to define an interface, and then have your (data) classes inherit from that.

Comment: thats how I have it now, but the problem is the copy method having a method copy(pop1:Long) in the interface does not use the data class one

Comment: You could just have a [`sealed class`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) or an interface and then use reflection with named arguments, although it probably would make sense to rethink your problem. This is an unusual use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using an interface for that particular problem. Just delegate to the data class `copy` in the implementation.

```
data class MyData(val pop1: Long, val pop2: String) : Pop1Data {
    override fun copy(pop1: Long) {
        copy(pop1 = pop)
    }
}

interface Pop1Data {
    fun copy(pop1: Long)
}

class MyGenericClass<T : Pop1Data>(private val o: T) {
    // This is the important part
    fun useCopy(value: Long) = o.copy(value)
}
```

Comment: And how about the scenario when I have multiple and variant properties of some data classes? Is there a way to handle this scenario?

Comment: I haven't check this solution yet for my scenario, but I think it would be possible to pass into generic _copy()_ method a whole interface instead of just property and due inheritance convert the actual argument to the specific type, e.g. `override fun copy(obj: PopData) { copy(param1 = (obj as Pop1Data).pop1, isCompleted =  (obj as Pop1Data).pop2) }`